# html css submit button

Tags: html, css

I have fallows a couple of things on stacked over flow and can not seem to figure out how to get this simple line to work

```
<a class="lp-element lp-pom-button" id="lp-pom-button-25"><span class="label" style="margin-top: -10px;">Get Notified!</span></a>
```

It is suppose to be a submit button and whenever I change it to this

```
<a class="lp-element lp-pom-button" id="lp-pom-button-25" type="submit" name="submit"><span class="label" style="margin-top: -10px;">Get Notified!</span></a>
```

It still dosnt submit to the php form.

All help is greatly appreciated. you can view it on the page below to get a perspective of what I am doing

```
keyinventory[dot]com
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be using a `<button type="submit">` or `<input type="submit">` element instead if you want to submit the form. I don't believe normal links can be used to submit a form without javascript.

A more complete example using your existing code would be:

`<button type="submit" class="lp-element lp-pom-button" id="lp-pom-button-25" name="submit"><span class="label" style="margin-top: -10px;">Get Notified!</span></button>`

Comment: Thank you so much I knew it would be something simple but couldn't figure it out.